# Categorical treemap in R does not show all the categories

Tags: r, treemap

I was playing with treemaps in R and when I try categorical treemap, the treemap shows only one category. I wanted to reproduce treemap [examples](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/buildexamples_treemap.html) in Tableau but the categorical example is not giving me a correct treemap. The data is public and it is from Tableau website. It can be downloaded from [here](https://community.tableau.com/servlet/JiveServlet/download/351988-57774/Sample%20-%20Superstore.xls).

If I want to color the rectangles by a numeric column, it works fine.

```
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
Sample_Superstore <- read_excel("Sample_Superstore.xls")
grouped=Sample_Superstore%>%select(`Sub-Category`,Sales,`Ship Mode`)%>%
           group_by(`Sub-Category`,`Ship Mode`)%>%summarise(Total_Sales=sum(Sales))
```

### Numeric column for coloring (works fine!)

```
treemap(grouped, 
 index="Sub-Category", 
 vSize="Total_Sales", 
 vColor="Total_Sales",
 type="value",
 title = "",
 palette="BuGn", #"Blues" 
 border.col ="white"
)
```

[image]

#### Using categorical variable for coloring (not working)

It shows only one category but my data has four categories.

```
treemap(grouped, 
 index="Sub-Category", 
 vSize="Total_Sales",  
 vColor="Ship Mode",
 type="categorical"
)
```

[image]

Comment: The data I downloaded from your link seems not to be exactly the same as yours (probably an update), which makes it difficult to investigate

Comment: I provided a wrong link for the data. I have edited it.

Comment: Is it possible to use a color palette in each category? I want the bigger rectangles to be deeper color

Comment: Not exactly what you want but... `treemap(grouped, 
        index=c("Ship Mode", "Sub-Category"), 
        vSize="Total_Sales",  
        vColor="Total_Sales",
        type="value"
)` ... (back to one palette, but we keep groups). Don't know if it's possible

Comment: I mean one color palette in each category. I have data that has "failed" and "warning" categories and I want to use different color palettes for each one of them.

Comment: I am looking for something like this: https://www.google.com/search?q=tableau+treemap&rlz=1C1RUCY_enUS718US718&espv=2&biw=1536&bih=736&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiom4uxwrrRAhXGz1QKHTQVCD8Q_AUIBigB#imgrc=ZmYXMLzgXIOQNM%3A

Comment: Ok then you've got the simple `treemap(grouped, 
        index=c("Ship Mode", "Sub-Category"), 
        vSize="Total_Sales",  
        type="index"
)` but it's not ordered by sales... I was working on `treepalette()` but it seems complicated

Comment: Thanks! That uses different color palettes for each class. Can i specify the palettes. I want to use a reddish palette for "failed" and orange palette for  "warning".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
treemap(grouped, 
        index=c("Ship Mode", "Sub-Category"), 
        vSize="Total_Sales",  
        vColor="Ship Mode",
        type="categorical"
)
```

[image]